# Unexpected failure in transactions with isolation level serializable

Tags: postgresql

Unexpected failure in transactions with isolation level serializable

Hi,

I have a challenge with transactions in Postgresql when they have the isolation level SERIALIZABLE.

This is the transaction table and data:

```
CREATE TABLE "test_transaction"
(
  "id" bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
  "other_id" bigint NOT NULL,
  "created_time" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  "updated_time" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
);

INSERT INTO "test_transaction"
    ("id", "other_id")
    VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (2, 2),
    (3, 1),
    (4, 2),
    (5, 1),
    (6, 2);
```

Start transaction A:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE READ WRITE;
```

Start transaction B:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE READ WRITE;
```

Select the last transaction with "other_id"=1 in transaction A:

```
select 
  "test_transaction"."id", 
  "test_transaction"."other_id", 
  "test_transaction"."created_time", 
  "test_transaction"."updated_time" 
from 
  "test_transaction" 
where 
  "test_transaction"."other_id" = 1 
order by 
  "test_transaction"."updated_time" desc limit 1;
```

Select the last transaction with "other_id"=2 in transaction B:

```
select 
  "test_transaction"."id", 
  "test_transaction"."other_id", 
  "test_transaction"."created_time", 
  "test_transaction"."updated_time" 
from 
  "test_transaction" 
where 
  "test_transaction"."other_id" = 2 
order by 
  "test_transaction"."updated_time" desc limit 1;
```

Update "updated_time" where id = 1 in transaction A:

```
update 
  "test_transaction" 
set 
  "updated_time" = now()
where 
  "test_transaction"."id" = 5
returning 
  "test_transaction"."id", 
  "test_transaction"."other_id", 
  "test_transaction"."created_time", 
  "test_transaction"."updated_time";
```

Update "update_time" where id = 2 in transaction B:

```
update 
  "test_transaction" 
set 
  "updated_time" = now()
where 
  "test_transaction"."id" = 6
returning 
  "test_transaction"."id", 
  "test_transaction"."other_id", 
  "test_transaction"."created_time", 
  "test_transaction"."updated_time";
```

Commit transaction A:

```
COMMIT;
```

Commit transaction B:

```
COMMIT;
```

Recieve an error in transaction B

```
ERROR: could not serialize access due to read/write dependencies among transactions
SQL state: 40001
Detail: Reason code: Canceled on identification as a pivot, during commit attempt.
Hint: The transaction might succeed if retried.
```

Not sure what goes wrong in transaction B as I think that transaction A and B should work on each set and only lock sets where other_id equals 1 and 2 respectively. But it seems like the entire table is protected?

I have tested the same with "Repeatable Read" isolation level and which works perfectly. I can see that it should be "Phantom Read" that is allowed here.

Can someone shred some light on what goes on here as I expected it would work without any issues?

Comment: This is interesting. Does it also happen if you add an index on `(other_id, updated_time)`?

Comment: Side-note: `SERIALIZABLE` doesn't promise never to cancel a transaction that is safe. Applications should *always* be ready to retry any transaction when using `SERIALIZABLE` isolation. Then again, well written apps should be ready to retry any xact in `READ COMMITTED` too, to cope with server restarts, deadlock aborts, etc. Keep all the data until you get commit confirmation. Be ready to retry.

Comment: I got the same behaviour when adding the index. Postgresql version is 9.5.5 on ubuntu for the test.

Comment: Thanks Craig, that did clarify things a bit. Seems like Postgresql does not apply any "smart" logic in this scenario. Currently using a retry strategy but unfortunate there are quite a lot of activity and hence a lot of collisions.

Answer (score 0):

(sorry for the necro bumping)

I have a similar problem with PostgreSQL 12.8. From my understanding, it's because postgres would escalate the row lock to a page lock/table lock, based on the query plan.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html

> Predicate locks in PostgreSQL, like in most other database systems, are based on data actually accessed by a transaction. These will show up in the pg_locks system view with a mode of SIReadLock. The particular locks acquired during execution of a query will depend on the plan used by the query, and multiple finer-grained locks (e.g., tuple locks) may be combined into fewer coarser-grained locks (e.g., page locks) during the course of the transaction to prevent exhaustion of the memory used to track the locks.

I also tried to add an index, which didn't help. However, if I temporary use `set enable_seqscan = off`, to prevent the Seq scan, then I don't have the problem anymore (but I can't use that setting in production).

I know it's not an answer, but I hope it helps a little bit.